# useRef() Hook on a custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying do create a Navigation Bar that when the user clicks on one of the links, the page scrolls to some section. In the code above, each element is a section of my page:

```
    <Navbar scrollFunc={scrollToRef} />      
    <Mainlogo ref={mainLogoRef} />
    <Sales  ref={salesRef} />
    <Introduction ref={introductionRef} />
    <Blog ref={blogRef} />
    <Footer />
```

The 'refs' was declared as following, using the `useRef` hook:

```
  const mainLogoRef = useRef(null)
  const salesRef = useRef(null)
  const introductionRef = useRef(null)
  const blogRef = useRef(null)
```

The function I'm using to scroll is the following:

```
  const scrollToRef = ref => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: ref.current.offsetTop, behavior: "smooth" })
  }
```

The thing is that the 'current' key is always undefined. When I do something like that:

```
<div ref={salesRef}> <Sales  /><div>
```

or

```
<section ref={salesRef}> <Sales  /><section>
```

Things works just fine. I'm assuming that 'ref' works only on html 'pure' tags. Is there any way to use `useRef` hook in a custom component?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

On custom components, `ref` needs to be [forwarded](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

An example would be like:

```
// inside Sales.js
const Sales = (props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref}> // assigns the ref to an actual DOM element, the div
    /* anything you want to render here */
  </div>
)

export default React.forwardRef(Sales);
```

This is because `ref` is (usually) a reference to a DOM element. A React Component can renders multiple DOM element, so you need to be explicit about where the `ref` should be assigned to.

Comment: I believe the gist of your answer is correct, although I think the component function's signature should probably be `const Sales = ({ ref, ...props }) =>` since the first argument to functional components is always the `props` object and `ref` is a prop.

Comment: Taken straight from the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

"Note:
The second ref argument only exists when you define a component with React.forwardRef call. Regular function or class components don’t receive the ref argument, and ref is not available in props either."

Comment: Worked just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and link to the docs, @Jackyef. I neglected to see the `React.forwardRef` call in your solution.

Comment: For functional components, use fowardRef on the component itself - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62133013/228369