# React FC with forwardedRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im facing issue with ref - I need to ref to function component and pass props to it. So far I got my Parent component and Child Component. In my parent component I need to use ref to my child. I need to work with projectSectionItem inside my parent component.

**Parent:**

```
const projectSectionItem = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

        return i.showOnHP === 1 ?
            <Project key={index}
                url={`${URL}${i.button_image.image}`}
                client={i.client_name}
                project={i.project.en}
                btn_color={"#000"}
                btn_text={i.button_text}
                href={`/cases/${i.slug}`}
                ref={projectSectionItem}
            >
                {index === 0 ?
                    <ScrollList>
                        {data.map((i, index) => { return <ScrollListItem data-index={index} key={index} ref={projectIndicator} onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => scrollToNextProject(e)} /> })}
                    </ScrollList>
                    : null}
            </Project>
                : null;
        })}
```

**Child:**

```
type APIProps = {
    url?: string,
    client?: string,
    project?: string,
    btn_text?: string,
    btn_color?: string,
    href?: string,
}

type HWWProps = {
    order_client?: number,
    order_project?: number,
    className?: string
    ref?: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>
}

type ProjectProps = APIProps & HWWProps;

export const Project: React.FC<ProjectProps> = props => {
    return (
        <StyledProject className={props.className}>
            <ProjectContainer>
                <ProjectImage src={props.url} alt={props.client} />
                <ProjectTextWrapper>
                    <ProjectBrand order_client={props.order_client}>{props.client}</ProjectBrand>
                    <ProjectName order_project={props.order_project}>{props.project}</ProjectName>
                    <ButtonExtend as={Button} color={props.btn_color}><Link to={props.href}>{props.btn_text}</Link></ButtonExtend>
                </ProjectTextWrapper>
            </ProjectContainer>
            {props.children}
        </StyledProject>
    )
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have mixed up Parent and Child component in your code. Also what problem are you facing?

Comment: I cant access Ref inside my child I need to use on project something like ref={projectSectionItem}, I added to my parent forwardRef, but didnt get it, how to make it work with other props like className etc.

Comment: Project isn't a parent right, its a child and also even though you are using forwardRef, you aren't passing the ref to anything?

Comment: I edit my topic how it looks like, without ref. So right now I need to useRef on my Project(child).

Comment: What do you want to achieve with refs. I don't you passing ref to anything wihitn the Project component. Also with functional components you need to use forwardRef and implement useImperativeHandle

Comment: I want to get projectSectionItem.current inside my child component then work with it. My qustion is, how to ref to my Function Component(Parent Project)

Comment: Work with it how. Also note that your Project isn't a parent component but a Child. You seem to be confused

Comment: Ups. You are right sorry, I updated everything and right now it should be clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215099/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-mckvak).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot add refs to functional component without using `React.forwardRef` to either pass it on to a HTMLDIVElement or using `useImperativeHandle` hook to expose some functions

Since you wish to add the ref a DOM element in Project component you can pass the ref on to the StyledProject component which is a styled component by using innerRef prop

```
export const Project: React.FC<ProjectProps> = React.forwardRef((props ,ref: : Ref<HTMLDivElement>)=> {
    return (
        <StyledProject className={props.className} innerRef={ref}>
            <ProjectContainer>
                <ProjectImage src={props.url} alt={props.client} />
                <ProjectTextWrapper>
                    <ProjectBrand order_client={props.order_client}>{props.client}</ProjectBrand>
                    <ProjectName order_project={props.order_project}>{props.project}</ProjectName>
                    <ButtonExtend as={Button} color={props.btn_color}><Link to={props.href}>{props.btn_text}</Link></ButtonExtend>
                </ProjectTextWrapper>
            </ProjectContainer>
            {props.children}
        </StyledProject>
    )
});
```

After doing this, you can access the ref in parent like `projectSectionItem.current`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63932779/13094333 Looks like it would work, but this answer seems to be doing the same, but more elegantly.