# Type error with passing `ref` prop when using `forwardRef`

Tags: typescript

I'm running into a TS error when trying to type a container that forwards a ref.

Here's the code:

```
// Container.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div``;

interface ContainerProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
const Container: React.FC<ContainerProps> = React.memo(
  React.forwardRef((props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    return <Wrapper ref={ref} {...props} />;
  })
);

export default Container;
```

```
// Typography.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Container from "./Container";

const ContainerStyled = styled(Container)``;

interface TypographyProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
const Typography: React.FC<TypographyProps> = React.memo(({ children }) => {
  const handleContainerRef = React.useCallback((ref: HTMLDivElement) => {
    console.log("ref", ref);
  }, []);

  return <ContainerStyled ref={handleContainerRef}>{children}</ContainerStyled>;
//                        ^^^ Property 'ref' does not exist on type
});

export default Typography;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: stoic-sea-ycg3ls]

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62133013/15032132

> You cannot add refs to functional component without using React.forwardRef

**So, in this particular case, you can remove the `React.FC` type from the Container and add the generic types to `React.forwardRef`.**

```
const Container = React.memo(
  React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ContainerProps>(
    (props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      return <Wrapper ref={ref} {...props} />;
    }
  )
);
```